# Do you need to Git Config for new computer but same GitHub account?

Tags: git, github, config

Let's say I have one computer that has Git and it works great in VSC. Then I get a new computer, but I still use the old computer too. Do I need to do the Git config on my new computer, even though the Github account is the same? What I ended up doing was I did do Git config on my new computer too and everything works just fine, but I am wondering if it was actually necessary to config Git on a new computer but same Github account. I guess another way to word my question is whether Git config is specific to computers or the Github account system.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "do Git config"?

Comment: github is a website, so getting a new computer doesn't affect it. I think a git config would have little to do with github.

Comment: Git config I mean git config set up username and git config email. Every time I use Git for first time it always forces me to login to Github too that's why I was wondering if they were connected in any way.

Comment: git is version control software. github is a website/service which hosts git repos, just like bitbucket, gitlab, etc

Comment: Yeah I know. So I guess I would need to Git config on each new computer.

Comment: Yes, and no. You can use git without initialising any git config (by using defaults). Also the are different levels of a git config. The system, user, and repo. The username/email is only an identifier for the commit author. This can be any username/email. It doesn't have to be one associated with a github account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Git committer and author information is completely independent of any GitHub, GitLab or Bitbucket accounts. Git is a version control system (sometimes also "source control/code management"), and GitHub is a platform for hosting Git repositories. Git can be used without any hosting provider – either locally or with your own server.

Git committer/author information (`git config user.name`, `git config user.email`) is used when you create commits.

Website credentials (or SSH keys) are used when you interact with a remote website (`git push`, `git fetch`). Only when you interact with a remote repository hosting website, then you will need to authenticate yourself to the remote site.

TL;DR: **yes**, you need to copy/reconfigure your Git config to your new PC if you want to have the same configuration and use the same name for your commits.